# GVIM. Plugin log4j doesn't work

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Version: gvim, version 7.4.52
OS: Linux Mint 17

.vimrc (only 2 lines!):

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.log set syntax=log4j
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile program_log set syntax=log4j
```

.vim directory in home:

```
-syntax (directory)
--log4j.vim (plugin's file)
```

Result: all my *.log and program_log looks "black and white".

UPDATE
output of `:scriptnames` (for file.log):

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/menu.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/paste.vim
  9: ~/.vimrc
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/gvimrc
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim74/scripts.vim
```

Colorscheme by default.
Syntaxes for files from `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax` work well (java, css, html, etc).
After opening `*.log` I tried following commands: `:syntax on` `:set filetype=log4j` etc, but log4j-plugin ignores me.

UPDATE2
When app.php, :scriptnames consists:

```
21: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/php.vim
22: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim
23: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/javascript.vim
```

it's ok and i see highlight, but when logs.log - fail..

Comment: Other syntaxes work (you have `:syntax on`)? What's the output of `:scriptnames`; is the `syntax/log4j.vim` loaded?

Comment: As it turned out, other syntaxes doesn't work too.. I've updated my question.

Comment: Looks like you have `:syntax on`, and the syntax script is loaded. Do you see colors when you do `:hi`? What colorscheme do you use?

Comment: I've updated my question again. You were right, after opening i typed :syntax on, therefore scriptnames was with ~/.vim/syntax/log4j.vim, but highlight didn't set. Yes, I see column with different colors. My colorscheme set by default (for simplicity).

Comment: Based on your updated `:scriptnames` output, the syntax script isn't found. What's the value of `:set runtimepath?`, and is `~/.vim` listed in there (it should)? Do you have plugins, and are those loaded?

Comment: `:set runtimepath` output: `runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after`  I havn't any plugins. I've even tried to copy _log4j.vim_ into `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax`. Do I have any chance to see log's highlight? =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 
[log4jhighlighter](https://github.com/codelibra/log4jhighlighter/blob/master/log4j_syntax_highlighter.vim)
The installation details are present in github.

Comment: At last! My logs look nice now. Thanks! I was waiting your answer more than half of year!

Comment: Thanks @DmitMedv Please star the github repo, if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

> autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.log set syntax=log4j
>
> autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile program_log set syntax=log4j

`set syntax` is wrong at this point try `set filetype=log4j`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help.. What else can I check or try? Thx

Comment: You may check log-format.
From log4j.vim:

>" While it's possible to define any sort of pattern via PatternLayout (log4j)
" or LoggerLayoutPattern (log4php), this syntax file focuses on the default
" TTCC layout TTCC layout with conversion pattern set to:
"
" %d{m/d/y H:i:s,u} [%t] %p %c %x - %m%n